# Why #pragma message does not work in hpp file?

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-10.3-rio

When I insert

```
#pragma message("My custom error")
```

in the header file, this message is never displayed when the source is compiled.
When I insert it in the cpp file, it works as expected.

Is this the normal behaviour? I thought that #pragma message should work also in the hpp file.

Rad Studio Rio 10.3.1

**UDPATE:**

It seems that it only happens when `#include <vcl.h>` is added before the header.

For example, if in `Unit1.h` I have `#pragma message("My message")` and in the `Unit1.cpp` I have:

```
#include "Unit1.h"
```

it would show the message as expected. However if I have:

```
#include <vcl.h>
#include "Unit1.h"
```

then the message is not displayed.

Comment: I created a new C++Builder VCL app. In *unit3.cpp* and in *unit3.h* I added `#pragma message("This is unit3.cpp")` and `#pragma message("This is unit3.h")` respectively, and both messages showed up in the Messages pane. And yes, it should show display in the .hpp too.

Comment: `#pragma message` works just fine in hpp files. If you are not seeing your message being output, then the compiler is likely not seeing the `#pragma` to begin with, either because you are not actually `#include`'ing the hpp, or the `#pragma` is being skipped by an `#if(n)def` or `#if`

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  I have updated the question to replicate the problem from a new project. The problem is when I add `#include <vcl.h>` before the unit header.